# My cat hasn't defecated in 2 days

Tags: cats, health, defecation

My cat hasn't defecated in 2 days. He hasn't been neutered and he has been sleeping more than usual. We brought him outside a few days ago into our garden which we share with our neighbours dogs. They are brought outside often and I'm not quite sure what to do. He hasn't been to a vet. We found him on the street 4 years ago and we haven't done much yet except giving him clean water.

Answer (score 3):

I have jotted down the following points from the [The Most Common Cause of Kitty Constipation](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/dr-karen-becker/the-most-common-cause-of-_b_9189722.html) from the Huffington Post.

Constipation is a common problem in cats.

Signs of constipation -

1. The cat should poop every single day.
2. His stoll should be brown, formed (not loose), and soft and moist enough that litter sticks to them.

Causes of constipation -

1. Dehydration.
2. GI mobility problems.
3. Painful defacation due to fracture of the pelvis or hind limb, arthritis, or impacted anal glands.
4. Orthopedic or neurological problems.
5. Obstruction of the colon caused by a foreign object, tumor, or hernia.
6. Megacolon.

Treatment -

1. Try avoiding dry cat food. Add liquid from a can of tuna or other cat food into water bowel. Some prefer water from water fountain than still water.
2. Try to make sure your cat gets regular exercises.
3. You can add psyllium or coconut fiber in food.
4. If hair balls are the reason you can add coconut oil to food to ease hair movement through Gastro Intestinal track.
5. Smoe natural laxatives like aloe vera juice can be added to food.

If the problem still persists you should visit your vet.